# Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have the following equation, where there is a lot of stuff under the sum symbol:

```
\begin{equation}
d(\vec{x},\vec{y})=
  \sum_{Z_{xy}\in\vec{Z}_{xy},\forall x\in\vec{x},\forall y\in\vec{y}} 
    f(Z_{xy})
\end{equation}
```

In the resulting document, I find it kind of hard to read. Is there a way to write the equation to make the result more readable, e.g. putting the stuff under the sum symbol on different lines?

Comment: Why write under Sum, when mathematical correct is write to right.
`\begin{equation}
d(\vec{x},\vec{y})= \sum_{Z_{xy}\in\vec{Z}_{xy}} f(Z_{xy}),\forall x\in\vec{x},\forall y\in\vec{y}
\end{equation}`

Comment: I agree with you but without the correct spacing, it is as bad as OP's. To be super-picky about it, `forall` is not the same as `over all`. With `forall` the author is relying on the reader's understanding for bad notation.

Comment: This is mathematically *incorrect* (if the notation has not introduced formally). But the `\forall` is definitely misused.

Comment: which font are you using? I love your \sum symbol

Comment: If you want to write a fraction instead, refer to [amsmath - In math mode, how do I make the fraction bar "invisible"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/589142/in-math-mode-how-do-i-make-the-fraction-bar-invisible).

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can use the `\substack` command from the `amsmath` package, like this:

```
\begin{equation}
  d(\vec{x},\vec{y}) =
  \sum_{\substack{Z_{xy}\in\vec{Z}_{xy}\\
                  \forall x\in\vec{x}\\
                  \forall y\in\vec{y}}}
        f(Z_{xy}) 
\end{equation}
```

However, the result still doesn’t look good, because of the extra spacing around the sum symbol:

[image: Image showing the result of the ‘\substack’ command]

To fix this, you can use the `\mathclap` command from the `mathtools` package, like this:

```
\begin{equation}
 d(\vec{x},\vec{y}) =
    \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{Z_{xy}\in\vec{Z}_{xy}\\
                              \forall x\in\vec{x}\\
                               \forall y\in\vec{y}}}}
          f(Z_{xy}) 
\end{equation}
```

[image: Image showing the result of the ‘\mathclap’ and ‘\substack’ commands]

But perhaps you might be happy using **only** `\mathclap`, and not `\substack`. The result looks good as long as the subscript is not too wide.

```
\begin{equation}
  d(\vec{x},\vec{y}) =
    \sum_{\mathclap{{Z_{xy}\in\vec{Z}_{xy},
          \forall x\in\vec{x},
          \forall y\in\vec{y}}}} f(Z_{xy})
\end{equation}
```

[image: Image showing the result of the ‘\mathclap’ command]

The [`mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) also have several other useful commands for typesetting mathematics, including more commands for improving the display of subscripts and superscripts. I very much recommend taking a look at [its documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf).

Comment: The `\forall` symbols should be omitted.

Comment: @egreg: Maybe one should just write _three_ sums in total, the first two over `x\in\vec{x}` and `y\in\vec{y}`?

Comment: @HendrikVogt I'd use a two line `\substack`: `\sum_{\substack{Z_{xy}\in\vec{Z}_{xy}\\x\in\vec{x},y\in\vec{y}}}`

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer You forgot ` \\ `.

Comment: Looks good, but seems not to work in `rmarkdown`'s `beamer_presentation`s. Can that be confirmed?

Answer (score 23):

Try the `\substack` command from the `amsmath` package, details of which are found [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)

Comment: In case anyone else needs that old link: https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

Comment: @psitae --- An ftp link! I've been here a long time. I've updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**[For those who are looking for MathJax way]** it can be done without `\substack` as

```
\sum_{a=b \\ b=c \\ c=a}
```

wich results in

[image]

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. I am in the 'align' environment.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, either.

Comment: This definitely doesn’t work in LaTeX. Unfortunately, it does in MathJax, which is not a reason for advertising it here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `A \atop B`. E.g:

```
\sum_{{n\in \mathbb{N}}\atop{n= even}}^{100} a_n
```

[image]