# Multiple subscripts

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

I'm trying to produce a product which has two subindices. Like this:

`\[ \phi_n(X)=\prod_{z\in \mu_n \\ z \textup{primitive}} (X-z) \]`

That doesn't work: the `\\` is not recognized.

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344 explains what you need.

Comment: Wonderful, that's exactly what I needed. I guess I didn't search using the correct terms. Thanks!

Comment: If the above linked question solved your problem this question should be closed as duplicate. I can do that if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

The line break `\\` doesn't work inside math like that. You can use e.g. `\shortstack` to stack the indices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ \phi_n(X)=\prod_{\shortstack{$\scriptstyle z\in \mu_n $\\$\scriptstyle z \textup{primitive}$}} (X-z) \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `\prod_{\substack{z\in \mu_n \\ z \textup{ primitive}}} (X-z)` ?

Comment: @Bruno: I didn't now `\substack` before. It seems to be the better solution. The `\shortstack` macro is however also useful in other situations (e.g. textmode) where things have to be stacked.