# How to type a double limit?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

I'm interested in typesetting the following double-limit:

[image]

Comment: `\[\lim_{\substack{x\rightarrow0\\y\rightarrow0}}x^y=1\]`

Comment: If the linked question doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to explain why and we'll reopen it.  Closing as a duplicate is just a way of ensuring that people who find this question easily find the other one.