# Inserting new line under \exists in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

Minimal example of my document. I'm using redesigned `exists`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\stdexists\exists
\renewcommand{\exists}{\mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathchoice
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\huge$\stdexists$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\Large$\stdexists$}}}{\stdexists}{\stdexists}}\displaylimits}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\exists_{j\in S j\neq i}\exists_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {p_{ij}}^{(n)}>0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This code gives an output:

[image]

What I need is:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\substack` command from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\stdexists\exists
\renewcommand{\exists}{\mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathchoice
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\huge$\stdexists$}}}
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\Large$\stdexists$}}}{\stdexists}{\stdexists}}\displaylimits}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\exists_{\substack{j\in S \\ j\neq i}}\exists_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {p_{ij}}^{(n)}>0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```