# Getting arguments underneath \min in an align environment

Tags: math-mode, align

I am wondering how can I ensure that an argument gets placed underneath \min when I use an align environment.

When I use math mode and write

```
\[
min_{x_1,\dots x_T} 
\]
```

the `{x_1,\dots x_T}` is placed directly underneath min.

However when I use an align environment and write

```
\begin{align*}
  min_{x_1\dots x_T} 
\end{align*}
```

the `{x_1,\dots x_T}` is placed to the bottom left of `\min`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Also, did you mean to use `$...$` in the first example instead of `\[ ... \]`? Or perhaps you just meant `\min` instead of `min`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The macro is `\min`, not `min`.

When you use `\min` in display mode (ie, within `\[ \min_{<subscript>} \]`, or within the `align` environment), the subscript is placed underneath by default.

When you use `\min` in inline math mode (ie, with `$\min_{<subscript>}$`), then you need to
specify `\displaystyle`, or `\limits` to get the subscript underneath.

All four below produce:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Inline mode:
$\displaystyle \min_{x_1,\dots x_T}$
$\min\limits_{x_1,\dots x_T}$

\bigskip
Display mode:
\[ \min_{x_1,\dots x_T} \]
%
\begin{align*} 
    \min_{x_1\dots x_T} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I want more things to be displayed underneath the $$x_1 \dots x_T $$, say I want to also put in the minimization the constraint $$ \sum^T_{t=1} x_t $$.

Comment: @CharlieParker: You use `\substack` at [Expression under summation on multiple lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80461/4301) and [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33358/4301).  If that does not solve your issue, please post a new question.