# Expression under summation on multiple lines

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

I want to write expression `\sum_{i=0}^n i` with `i\neq 4` under the
summation symbol. How can I write this?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

You can use `\substack`:

[image]

If this is desired in inline math you can use `\limits` to obtain the limits underneath the summation symbol:

[image]

However this is not recommended as it may not look good depending on how much adjacent text there is as it will affect interline spacing.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sum_{\substack{i=0 \\ i\neq 4}}^n i
\]

In inline math: $\sum_{\substack{i=0 \\ i\neq 4}}^n i$, or
$\sum\limits_{\substack{i=0 \\ i\neq 4}}^n i$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the `\substack` content is too wide, you can use `\mathclap`, as detailed in [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33358/1913)

Comment: Will it work for `\underset{}{}` as well using `\text{}` inside?

Comment: @Royi: Probably best to ask a new question with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem you are having.