# How can I write a double expression below de comand \argmin for explain the range of two variables?

Tags: math-operators, subscripts

How can I write a double expression below de comand \argmin for explain the range of two variables

Comment: The following answer might help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284054/63983

Comment: Once you have `\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min}` in your preamble, use `\argmin_{\substack{x\in X\\y\in Y}}` in your document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80461/4427

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax) See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80461/4427