# How can I write a latex fraction without a bar?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

I'm trying to write a math formula like this:

```
\sum_{ \frac{n=0}{(n+k-i) \text{~even}} }^{k-i}
```

This looks just as I want it, but I don't want the bar between n=0 and (n+k-i) text.

[image]

I tried using the `matrix` env,

```
\sum_{ \begin{matrix}{n=0}\\{(n+k-i) \text{~even}}\end{matrix} }^{k-i}
```

[image]

But that looks really bad, because the (n+k-i) text is too large.

Comment: I think you want `substack` there's quite a few very similar question on this site, like [separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines). Let us know if it's not a duplicate :)

Comment: There is an answer [using genfrac](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=14773), basically `\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{x}{y}`

Comment: Another solution is to use a `minipage` with limited width

Comment: For future visitors: if you really want to write a fraction, refer to [amsmath - On \atop again: how to obtain the same result without warning - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119096/on-atop-again-how-to-obtain-the-same-result-without-warning).

Answer (score 9):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\substack{n=0\\ (n+k-i)~\mathrm{even}}}^{k-i}
\]
\end{document}
```

maybe this is what you want to achieve.