# On \atop again: how to obtain the same result without warning

Tags: amsmath

I know this question has been already discussed but the answer does not seem to work in my case.

I am using the `\atop` command with the `amsmath` package to stack two symbols (more specifically `$a=x$` and `$b=y$`) but, as well known, this is foreign to LaTeX.

The standard reply I found (and LaTeX warning suggestion) is to use `\frac` or `\genfrac`, but these will insert a line between the two symbols, that I do not want. The other suggestion is to use `\overset`, but this treats the symbol below as  main and prints it bigger than the one above.

How do I obtain the same result as `\atop` without getting the LaTeX warning?

Comment: See the `stackengine` and/or the `tabstackengine` package.

Comment: Note: if the use case is something like multiple lines of math instead of fraction-like, refer to [equations - Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

Answer (score 33):

`\genfrac` won't produce a line if the third argument (which control the thickness of the rule) is set to `0pt`; the syntax for `\genfrac` is

```
\genfrac{<left-delim>}{<right-delim>}{<thickness>}{<mathstyle>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>}
```

A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\mycom[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
$A\mycom{a=x}{b=y}B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina sorry, I hadn't looked back at this.  Your answer is more complete.  It's all yours.

Comment: Note that this will make it 0.4pt taller than a `\frac` in `\textstyle`. Refer to [amsmath - In math mode, how do I make the fraction bar "invisible"? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/589142/in-math-mode-how-do-i-make-the-fraction-bar-invisible) for details.

Answer (score 12):

The question does not tell the context, where the symbol stacking is used.

- `\genfrac` is shown in the other answer(s). It also uses the next smaller math style if available.
- `\substack` can be used in limits, because it does not change the math style:

Example using `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
   \sum_{a=x \atop b=y}^{\text{atop}}
   \quad
   \sum_{\substack{a=x\\b=y}}^{\text{substack}}
   \quad
   \sum_{a=x}^{\text{normal}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can use \underset 
see the following example

```
\begin{equation}
\prod\limits_{\underset{j\ne h}{j = 1}}^{4K} {\Gamma \left( {{a_h} - {a_j}} \right)} 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A quick hint: If you indent lines of code by four spaces, the site software will pretty-print them automatically. Separately, I think you should mention in your answer that `\underset` requires loading of the `amsmath` package and (even more importantly) that the second argument will be typeset in a smaller font than the first. This behavior is quite different from that of `\substack`, which does *not* impose a font size change from the one row to the next.