# My TeX file can not reat \qatop and \func

Tags: errors

I want to open a latex file but it gives error , it can not understand

```
\QATOP
```

and

```
 \func
```

```
\begin{equation}
Li_{-r}\left( x\right) =\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{r}\left\langle \QATOP{r}{j}%
 \right\rangle x^{r-j}}{\left( 1-x\right) ^{r+1}} \label{3}
\end{equation}% 


\begin{equation*} \zeta \left( s\right) =\frac{1}{\Gamma \left( s\right) }\int_{0}^{\infty }t^{s-1}\frac{e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}dt\text{ \ for }\func{Re}\left( s\right) >1% \text{.} \end{equation*} –
```

how can I resolve it

Comment: Can you give an example? The commands are not defined in standard classes or packages, so it's quite normal that TeX/LaTeX doesn't understand them.

Comment: Is your output from Scientific Word?  Then you should have to input `tcilatex` to get these definitions.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than trying to post code in the comments.  Also please post a complete file rather than snippets.

Comment: I don't have tcilatex, how can I get it?

Comment: A google search gives several hits.

Comment: E.g., `ftp://ftp.mackichan.com/sw25/updates/tcilatex.tex`.

Comment: is there any way to write $\left\langle \QATOP{r}{j}\right\rangle $ without \QATOP ?

Comment: `tcilatex.tex` contains `\def\QATOP#1#2{{#1 \atop #2}}`, so you can just put this definition at the top of your file.  `\atop` is now generally deprecated because of its strange syntax, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119096/15925 for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get this to compile is to insert

```
\input{tcilatex}
```

near the top of your file, having found a copy of `tcilatex.tex` and placed in the same directory as your file.  This is rather an old format, which I think comes from Scientific Word, and an alternative would be to provide new definitions.  However there are many so this will be quite a bit of work.  Anyway the two you ask for are covered by the following:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsopn}
\newcommand{\QATOP}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  Li_{-r}\left( x\right) =\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{r}\left\langle \QATOP{r}{j}%
 \right\rangle x^{r-j}}{\left( 1-x\right) ^{r+1}} \label{3}
\end{equation}% 


\begin{equation*}
  \zeta \left( s\right) =\frac{1}{\Gamma \left(
    s\right) }\int_{0}^{\infty }t^{s-1}\frac{e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}dt\text{
  \ for }\func{Re}\left( s\right) >1% 
  \text{.}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```