# Two rows of upper indices

Tags: math-mode

How do we do this in LaTeX? The main problem is having two rows of values as upper indices.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any package:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{shaft}=20^{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\scriptscriptstyle +0.080\\[-7pt]
\scriptscriptstyle +0.005
\end{array}}\mathrm{mm}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you define the argument of `array` as `@{}c@{}` instead of simply as `c`, you can dispense with the `\!\!` directives.

Comment: @Mico You're absolutely right, what nonsense!

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the low-level commands are just nicer in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathrm{shaft = 20^{+0.080\atop +0.005} mm} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `amsmath`, it will nag but does compile. However, it has been said it's better to use the higher-level macros with LaTeX, and so borrowing from [Gonzalo's answer from a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119098/1410), one might use something like the following with `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\scriptstack[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
%\genfrac{<left-delim>}{<right-delim>}{<thickness>}{<mathstyle>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathrm{shaft = 20^{\scriptstack{+0.080}{+0.005}} mm}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can easily add an `amsmath` complying answer using `\genfrac`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \begin{document}
\[\text{shaft} = 20^{\substack{+0.080\\+0.005}}\,\text{mm}\]
        \end{document}
```

But this is not standard notation for tolerance. For it see `siunitx` package.
Edit:
As mentioned `Mico`, third line arise substack for one line and `\scriptscriptstyle` make indices smaller:
[image]
Corrected code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \begin{document}
\[\text{shaft} = 20^{\substack{\scriptscriptstyle+0.080\\\scriptscriptstyle+0.005\\~}}\,\text{mm}\]
        \end{document}
```

Comment: I think you may have to add `\scriptscriptstyle` in front of each element in the substack to make the numbers sufficiently small. Adding a third, empty, row may also be needed to raise the entire substack a bit more.

Comment: @Zarko Your solution is good but I prefer the other one

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using low level functions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mySI}{O{}mom}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {\SI[#1]{#2}{#4}}
   {\SI[parse-numbers=false,#1]{\num[parse-numbers=true]{#2}\douncert{#3}}{#4}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\douncert}{m}{%
  ^{%
   \vbox{
     \def\myrow##1{\num{##1}}
     \let\\=\cr\tiny
     \offinterlineskip\lineskip=1pt
     \halign{\myrow{##}\hfil\cr#1\crcr}
   }%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tvar}{m}{\textnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\tvar{shaft}=\mySI{20}[+0.080\\+0.005]{mm}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `\vcenter` instead of `\vbox`, the result would be

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that produces the same vertical spacing as the O.P.'s example, you can try the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{document}

\[\text{shaft} = 20^{\,\setstackgap{L}{2ex}\everymath{\scriptscriptstyle}\Vectorstack{+0.080\\+0.005}}\,\text{mm}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]