# Left justifying in \genfrac

Tags: amsmath, fractions

Is there an easy way to left-justify the "numerator" and "denominator" in \genfrac?  By default it centers  the "numerator" and "denominator."  I am using it for a custom \atop command, per suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119096/on-atop-again-how-to-obtain-the-same-result-without-warning/119098):

```
\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

Perhaps there is an alternative to \genfrac that provides all spacing/sizing functionality but allows one to customize justification?

Comment: Did you try `\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}
```

but if you want to use it under summation signs, the result will not be the best:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{\myatop{a}{bcd}}
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}a\\bcd\end{subarray}}
\sum_{1\le x\le n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can clearly see that `\myatop` produces too small characters.

---

When TeX typesets a fraction, it determines the width *w* to use and eventually typesets numerator and denominator with

```
\hbox to w{\hfil<subformula>\hfil}
```

With the setting above, this will become

```
\hbox to w{\hfil<subformula>\hfill\hfil}
```

and, being `\hfill` “more infinite” than `\hfil`, it kills the two standard spacers.

You get the same behavior with

```
\makebox[3cm]{text\hfill}
```

because this has `\hfil` on either side (actually `\hss`, but it's a minor detail) and `\hfil text\hfill\hfil` is equivalent to `text\hfill`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work!  I accept the answer, but idly wonder why \hfill provides the desired behavior...

Comment: @M.B.M. TeX implicitly adds `\hfil` around numerator and denominator of a fraction, and `\hfill` kills it.

Comment: Wow -- thanks for the extensive explanation!