# In math mode, how do I make the fraction bar "invisible"?

Tags: amsmath, fractions

I am trying to typeset a "fraction" without the fraction bar.  I have tried to do this using the `genfrac`, but as in the example below, the numerator and denominator in `genfrac` are farther apart than in `frac`.  How can I correct this?

I'm trying to create a table in which one of the entries ("cells") contains two entries -- one on top of the other -- as in row 5 in the MWE below.  In other words, I want to make the fraction bar "invisible" in the MWE table below.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

$\frac{1}{2}\;\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{1}{2}$

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    Row 1 & 1.23 & Some text.\\
    Row 2 & 7.89 & Additional text.\\
    Row 3 & 4.56 & More text.\\
    \addlinespace
    Row 4 & 1.23 & Some text.\\
    Row 5 & $\frac{\textit{A}:\;3.14}{\textit{B}:\;6.28}$ & Additional text.\\
    Row 6 & 4.56 & More text.\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: examples]

Comment: Just to make sure, you are aware that the usual approach is a row spanning `multirow`?  But this makes "Row 5" and "Additional text." twice as tall instead of the other entry half-sized.

Answer (score 8):

The `\frac` macro is defined as `\begingroup #1\endgroup \over #2` (for the definition enter `texdef -t latex \frac` in a terminal). You can redefine this to print the `\over` line in white:

```
\newcommand{\fracnoline}[2]{{\begingroup #1\endgroup \color{white}\over\color{black} #2}}
```

As Mico noted in comments, to generalize the macro in case the original color is not black you can use the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\fracnoline}[2]{\colorlet{foo}{.}{\begingroup #1\endgroup \color{white}\over\color{foo} #2}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fracnoline}[2]{\colorlet{foo}{.}{\begingroup #1\endgroup \color{white}\over\color{foo} #2}}

$\frac{1}{2}\;\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{1}{2}$

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    Row 1 & 1.23 & Some text.\\
    Row 2 & 7.89 & Additional text.\\
    Row 3 & 4.56 & More text.\\
    \addlinespace
    Row 4 & 1.23 & Some text.\\
    Row 5 & $\frac{\textit{A}:\;3.14}{\textit{B}:\;6.28} \fracnoline{\textit{A}:\;3.14}{\textit{B}:\;6.28}$ & Additional text.\\
    Row 6 & 4.56 & More text.\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1. Just in case the prevailing color isn't black, you may want to change `\newcommand{\fracnoline}[2]{{\begingroup #1\endgroup \color{white}\over\color{black} #2}}` to `\newcommand{\fracnoline}[2]{\colorlet{foo}{.}{\begingroup #1\endgroup \color{white}\over\color{foo} #2}}`. (The dot in `\colorlet{foo}{.}` picks up the prevailing color.)

Comment: @Mico thanks for your comment, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

That's a bit unexpected, I'll have to read appendix G again... but `\genfrac` is just exposing the underlying primitive and `\atop` and `\above0pt` both omit the rule but increase the height of the numerator. You can specify the negative width of the default rule (`-0.4pt`) to get the same height as `\frac` (which uses the `\over` primitive).

The first four forms here use the same height as`\frac`, the last three are higher.

[image]

Note this only applies to textstyle not displaystyle.

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\hrule
$
\frac{1}{2}\;
\genfrac{}{}{-.4pt}{}{1}{2}\;
{1 \above -.4pt 2}\;
{1\over 2}\;
{1 \above 0pt 2}\;
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{1}{2}\;
{1\atop 2}
$
\hrule
\smallskip
\hrule
$\displaystyle
\frac{1}{2}\;
\genfrac{}{}{-.4pt}{}{1}{2}\;
{1 \above -.4pt 2}\;
{1\over 2}\;
{1 \above 0pt 2}\;
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{1}{2}\;
{1\atop 2}
$
\hrule


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

With `amsmath` you can use the `\substack` command:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
 
  \begin{table}[!h]
   \begin{tabular}{lll}
    Row 1 & 1.23 & Some text.\\
    Row 2 & 7.89 & Additional text.\\
    Row 3 & 4.56 & More text.\\
    \addlinespace
    Row 4 & 1.23 & Some text.\\
    Row 5 & $ \substack{\textit{A}:\;3.14\\[1pt]\textit{B}:\;6.28}$ & Additional text.\\
    Row 6 & 4.56 & More text.\\
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The correct answer IMO, don't abuse a fraction to do this.

Comment: If you post that as an asnwer I can upvote it. I do agree. For tables, use table tools.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from David's answer, a fixed version that works in display, text and script style (not at scriptscript style, where other optimizations are used).

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\xabove}[2]{{%
  \mathpalette\fix@genfrac{{#1}{#2}}%
}}
\newcommand{\fix@genfrac}[2]{\fix@@genfrac#1#2}
\newcommand{\fix@@genfrac}[3]{%
  \genfrac{}{}{\fix@@@genfrac{#1}}{}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\fix@@@genfrac}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 0pt\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle -\fontdimen8\textfont2 \else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle -\fontdimen8\scriptfont2 \else
  0pt % but doesn't really work :-(
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\xabove{1}{2}$

$\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\xabove{1}{2}$

$\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2}\xabove{1}{2}$

%$\scriptscriptstyle\frac{1}{2}\xabove{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]