# Meter signature in text

Tags: symbols, music

I want to mention musical piece meter directly in the text, like:

*This piece is written in 4/4.*

Is there a way to get time signature (4/4) in form of fraction with no fraction bar?
I tried `musixtex` package but when I do:

`\begin{music}\meterfrac44\end{music}`

The fraction is much bigger than the rest of the text. Of course I can try to make it smaller to fit the text but maybe there's a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You could do something like `\newcommand*\meter[2]{\resizebox*{!}{.7\baselineskip}{\meterfrac{#1}{#2}}}` and then use `\meter{4}{4}` in the text. BTW: `\begin{music}` and `\end{music}` isn't actually needed here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. (You're right, I checked and environment is not needed - but it was not the reason for meter fraction to be so large.)

Comment: btw, isn't `C` used for `4/4` meter? (I understand that you want a general solution, I'm just making sure that I'm not missing some point.)

Comment: @tohecz: In my experience there is free variation between the two, as they are interchangeable.

Comment: @tohecz `C` might be used, but it's less popular nowadays (though I think widely understandable) and I have never encountered this in normal text, only in notation (but I don't posses much experience in this field).

Comment: Related, [equations - Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can propose two solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% solution 1
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\setmetera}[2]{\ensuremath{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}}

%%% solution 2
\newcommand{\setmeterb}[2]{\ensuremath{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
            $\scriptstyle#1$\cr
            \noalign{\vskip1pt}
            $\scriptstyle#2$\cr}
  }}%
}

\begin{document}
This is common time: \setmetera{4}{4}

This is a ternary time: \setmetera{3}{4}

\bigskip

This is common time: \setmeterb{4}{4}

This is a ternary time: \setmeterb{3}{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Some comments on the second solution

The definition of `\setmeterb` uses some low level TeX trickery. I use `\ensuremath` for being able to use `\vcenter` that will center the result with respect to the line (the "geometric center" will actually be slightly above the baseline).

In the `\vcenter` I set an alignment built with the primitive `\halign`, which avoids all the things LaTeX does with `tabular` in order to ensure equal spacing between rows, which is exactly what we *don't* want in this case where the two rows consist only of numbers; in particular the insertion of interline glue is disabled with `\offinterlineskip`. So the final trick is to set one centered column

```
\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr ...}
```

and then add the two rows, separated by 1pt of white space. The `#` must actually be `##` because we're using it in a definition.

Comment: Many thanks, I used solution2 and it looks very nice (I didn't want the fraction to make lines separator larger).

Answer (score 12):

I think the best way of implementing time signatures in the text is with the [lilyglyphs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lilyglyphs) package in combination with the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.

Here is an example:

[image]

The code to write this example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

These are common times: \lilyTimeSignature{4}{4}, \lilyTimeSignature{2}{4}, 
\lilyTimeSignature{6}{8}

\end{document}
```

Make sure you compile it with XeLaTeX!

Comment: I give you my sincere compliments.

Comment: This musical font brings back memories.  While all the answers are functional, this one is beautiful.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I approved your comment totally .

Answer (score 5):

Another simple and synthetic solution it to use `musicography` package: it is possible to compile starting with the engine `pdfLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musicography}
\begin{document}
This piece is written in \musMeter{4}{4} or in \textbf{\musMeter{4}{4}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can change the font to a more specific one.

Comment: You can also redefine `\musNumFont` to change the font in `\musMeter`.

Comment: @musarithmia Hi, and thank you very much for your feedback and the suggestion...You are authorized to edit my answer. Don't worry with me :-)....My best regards.

Comment: @musarithmia: how can I use `\musNumFont`? I'm trying with `\musNumFont{musix11}` but can't compile...

Comment: The argument to `\musNumFont` should be a complete LaTeX font command, like `\fontfamily{musix11}\selectfont`. I haven't tried using `musix11` for the numerals and would be curious to know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

A lightweight solution is `${}^{4}_{4}$` which renders as

[image: 4/4 time signature]

The initial {} captures that the following exponent and subscript are anchored to a blank.

Answer (score 1):

With MusiXTeX, I defined a command to do it (needs to be improved, but works):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\textmeter}{m m O{1.0} O{-3.0pt} O{0pt}}{%
    \adjustbox{scale=#3, raise=#4, margin=0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt, frame=#5}{%
    \setbox\toks@box\vbox{\hbox{\twelvebf#1}%
    \hbox{\twelvebf#2}}\vbox\@to15.5pt{\offinterlineskip
    \hbox\@to\wd\toks@box{\hfill\twelvebf#1\hfill}
    \hbox\@to\wd\toks@box{\hfill\twelvebf#2\hfill}}}%
}
```

You can use it as:

```
Some text \textmeter{2}{4} more text...
```

You can also check the `\notesintext` command in the MusiXTeX documentation.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks!!