# A new line inside subscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have formula:

```
\[ A_k = \bigcup_{I \subset \{ 1,...,k \} \text{card} J = K} B_j\]
```

which generates

[image: formula]

I would like ask how to make the new line inside subscript.
It should look like  formula below:

[image: correct formula]

I've tried with \newline and \begin{align*} but it doesn't work.

Comment: similar/related: [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12344/579)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `\substack`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ A_k = \bigcup_{\substack{I \subset \{ 1,\dots,k \}\\ \text{card} J = K}} B_j\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you feel that there is lot of empty space, here is how to get it out. This one uses `\mathclap` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[ A_k = \bigcup_{\mathclap{\substack{I \subset \{ 1,\dots,k \}\\ \text{card} J = K}}} B_j\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Response to comment**

It works inside `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    A_k &= \bigcup_{\mathclap{\substack{I \subset \{ 1,\dots,k \}\\ \text{card} J = K}}} B_j\\
    A_k &= \bigcup_{\mathclap{\substack{I \subset \{ 1,\dots,k \}\\ \text{card} J = K}}} B_j
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Inside align* block is conflict between \\ using by aling* and this which is used in substack block. How can I use substack inside align* block ?

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński: It works inside `align*`. See the update to my answer. If it is not working for you, please post the offending complete code to your question.

Comment: If you are using the mathtools package, it is better to use smaahoperator rather than mathcalp

Answer (score 5):

While not as streamlined as the accepted solution, I add this solution to the mix, because it shows the 2-line subscript left justified, as was provided in your example, which the accepted solution (to this point) does not.  I also made the subscript in `\scriptscriptstyle`, which may be preferable for a multi-line subscript.  Vertical gaps between the stacked lines are adjustable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\[ \def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackMath
  A_k = \mathop{\stackunder{\bigcup}{\def\stackalignment{l}%
    \stackunder[2pt]{\scriptscriptstyle I \subset \{ 1,...,k \}}
                    {\scriptscriptstyle\text{card} J = K}
  }} B_j\]

\[ \def\useanchorwidth{F}\stackMath
  A_k = \mathop{\stackunder{\bigcup}{\def\stackalignment{l}%
    \stackunder[2pt]{\scriptscriptstyle I \subset \{ 1,...,k \}}
                    {\scriptscriptstyle\text{card} J = K}
  }} B_j\]
\end{document}
```

[image]