# multlined breaks \substack?

Tags: mathtools, multline

I have some long equations to deal with that don't fit into one line, and love the `multlined`-environment from `mathtools` to fit them into (e.g.) an `align`-environment, particularly if I want to package 2-3 manipulations of the quantity requiring two lines into one block (in the MWE there's only one for brevity).

However, `multlined` breaks down when there's a `\substack` inside, see MWE below. It seems that the environment somehow tries to "`multline`" the `\substack`, but I haven't managed to prevent `multline` from "seeing" the `\substack` to avoid this.

MWE (using knowledge from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180549/42225 and the documentation):

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent A long equation using \texttt{multline} and \texttt{$\backslash$substack},
%
\begin{multline*}
    \mathcal{X}=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,\ell,m,n,p,q,r,s,t\\ i+j\equiv 1 \bmod{2}}}  \binom{...}{i} \binom{...}{j} \binom{...}{k} \binom{...}{\ell} \binom{...}{m} \binom{...}{n} \cdot\ldots\\
    \ldots \cdot \binom{...}{p} \binom{...}{q} \binom{...}{r} \binom{...}{s} \binom{...}{t},
\end{multline*}
%
breaks when using \texttt{multlined} instead of \texttt{multline},
%
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[2]% default is 2em
    \mathcal{X}\\
    &\!\begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth-\mathindent-2em-\multlinegap]
        =\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,\ell,m,n,p,q,r,s,t\\ i+j\equiv 1 \bmod{2}}}  \binom{...}{i} \binom{...}{j} \binom{...}{k} \binom{...}{\ell} \binom{...}{m} \binom{...}{n} \cdot\ldots\\
        \ldots \cdot \binom{...}{p} \binom{...}{q} \binom{...}{r} \binom{...}{s} \binom{...}{t},
    \end{multlined}\\
    &=1,
\end{align*}
%
but still works fine without \texttt{$\backslash$substack},
%
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[2]% default is 2em
    \mathcal{X}\\
    &\!\begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth-\mathindent-2em-\multlinegap]
        =\sum_{i,j,k,\ell,m,n,p,q,r,s,t}  \binom{...}{i} \binom{...}{j} \binom{...}{k} \binom{...}{\ell} \binom{...}{m} \binom{...}{n} \cdot\ldots\\
        \ldots \cdot \binom{...}{p} \binom{...}{q} \binom{...}{r} \binom{...}{s} \binom{...}{t}.
    \end{multlined}\\
    &=1,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nasty bug indeed.

Comment: clearly a bug ... somewhere ... i am trying to test it in some other contexts to determine whether the problem is with `amsmath` or `mathtools`; in either case, i'm adding it to the `amsmath` bugs list, as this is a reasonable construction that should be able to work without problems.

Comment: @egreg @barbarabeeton Note that the problem only happens in the first line. So it has to do with the first line trickery that `multlined` does behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of `stackengine` you can obtain:

[image]

In code below I borrow solution provided by author of `stacengine` in his answer in [A new line inside subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128508/a-new-line-inside-subscript/128518#128518):

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}

    \begin{document}
\noindent A long equation using \texttt{multline} and \texttt{$\backslash$substack},
%
\begin{multline*}
    \mathcal{X}=\sum_{\substack{i,j,k,\ell,m,n,p,q,r,s,t\\ i+j\equiv 1 \bmod{2}}}  \binom{...}{i} \binom{...}{j} \binom{...}{k} \binom{...}{\ell} \binom{...}{m} \binom{...}{n} \cdot\ldots\\
    \binom{...}{p} \binom{...}{q} \binom{...}{r} \binom{...}{s} \binom{...}{t},
\end{multline*}
%
breaks when using \texttt{multlined} instead of \texttt{multline},
%
\begin{align*}\def\useanchorwidth{T}\stackMath
%\MoveEqLeft[2]% default is 2em
\mathcal{X}
    &\begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth-\mathindent-2em-\multlinegap]
        =\mathop{\stackunder{\sum}{\def\stackalignment{c}%
               \stackunder[2pt]{\scriptscriptstyle i,j,k,\ell,m,n,p,q,r,s,t}
                               {\scriptscriptstyle i+j\equiv 1 \bmod{2}}
               }}  
        \binom{...}{i} \binom{...}{j} \binom{...}{k} \binom{...}{\ell} \binom{...}{m} \binom{...}{n} \cdot\ldots\\
        \ldots \cdot \binom{...}{p} \binom{...}{q} \binom{...}{r} \binom{...}{s} \binom{...}{t},
    \end{multlined}\\
    &=1,
\end{align*}
%
but works fine without \texttt{$\backslash$substack},
%
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[2]% default is 2em
    \mathcal{X}\\
    &\!\begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth-\mathindent-2em-\multlinegap]
        =\sum_{i,j,k,\ell,m,n,p,q,r,s,t}  \binom{...}{i} \binom{...}{j} \binom{...}{k} \binom{...}{\ell} \binom{...}{m} \binom{...}{n} \cdot\ldots\\
        \ldots \cdot \binom{...}{p} \binom{...}{q} \binom{...}{r} \binom{...}{s} \binom{...}{t}.
    \end{multlined}\\
    &=1,
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

It seems that `align`, `substack` and `multiline` doeasn't low each other very much :-(, i.e. here is present a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The spacing in  your solution is off, but all that can be fixed (`\displaystyle` for the `\sum`, `\scriptstyle` instead of `\scriptscriptstyle`, reintroduce `\!` before `multlined`, and replace `2em` with `\widthof{$\mathcal{X}$}` if commenting out `\MoveEqLeft`). I'll see if someone can find a fix for the original environments (so that I don't have to introduce another package), but if not, then I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Since nothing new regarding the bug to be forthcoming at the moment, I'm accepting your answer. Thanks again!