# Formatting of a star in the right upper corner of a product symbol

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I'm trying to get a star in the right upper corner of a product symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}
First variant in equation is bad:
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\prod_{i\in I}^\star
\end{equation}
Second variant in equation is good:
\begin{equation}\nonumber
{\prod_{i\in I}}^\star
\quad\text{but not completely:\quad}
{\prod_{\text{long text under the symbol}}}^\star
\end{equation}
First variant inline is good: $\prod_{i\in I}^\star$ and the second is bas: ${\prod_{i\in I}}^\star$.
\end{document}
```

Here a picture:

[image]

> How can I put this logic in a new command? And of course also solve the problem with the long text in equation.

Comment: See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines).

Comment: `\newcommand{\sprod}{\sideset{}{^*}\prod}`

Comment: @egreg ...except that `\sideset` always seems to place things in `\displaystyle`.  It also screws up subscript placement for inline usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\prodstar{\mathop{{\prod\nolimits^{\mathrlap{\star}}}}}
\begin{document}
Prodstar in equation is good:
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\prodstar_{i\in I}
\qquad\text{smaller styles:}\qquad
\scriptstyle \prodstar_{i\in I}\qquad
\scriptscriptstyle \prodstar_{i\in I}
\end{equation}
Prodstar is still good:
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\prodstar_{i\in I}
\quad\text{yes, completely:\quad}
\prodstar_{\text{long text under the symbol}}
\end{equation}
Prodstar inline is good: $\prodstar_{i\in I}$ and in the second case: $\prodstar_{i\in I}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the exhaustive answer and some humour that makes it even better

Comment: @PeptideChain The only issue that can arise is if you intend to use it with superscripts.  In displaystyle, the limit will sit a little high (that can be fixed by `\smash`ing the `\mathrlap`), in the smaller math styles, the superscript will clash with the star, unless space is manually added.