# Underbrace equation issues

Tags: equations, underbrace

I am trying to write this equation (see attached image)[image]

But I have been unsuccessful. So far I have this :

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq23}
  {C_E}^* = 
  \underbrace{{\underbrace{1 - a_{C_E}}_{\centering\text{Basic viscous
  resistance}}} +
  {\underbrace{{k_{C_E}({v_S}^*-1)}}_{\centering\text{ Linear correction viscous resistance}}} + {\underbrace{c_{C_E}.\Big(e{^{d_{C_E}}.{v_s}^*} - e^d_{C_E}\Big)}_{\text{Non-linear viscous correction resistance}}}_{\text{Viscous resistance}}} +
  {\underbrace{a_{C_E}}.e^{b_{C_E}({v_s}^*-1)}_{\centering\text{Wavemaking resistance}}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

Comment: You need `\substack`. See the linked question.

Answer (score 6):

I'd define a specialized macro for this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\underlabel}[3][]{{%
  \underbrace{#2}_{#1{\mbox{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#3\end{tabular}}}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq23}
{C_E}^* =
\underlabel{%
  \underlabel{1 - a_{C_E}}{Basic viscous \\ resistance} +
  \underlabel{k_{C_E}({v_S}^*-1)}{Linear correction \\ viscous resistance} +
  \underlabel{c_{C_E}(e{^{d_{C_E}}{v_s}^*} - e^d_{C_E})}
             {Non-linear viscous \\ correction resistance}
}{Viscous resistance} +
\underlabel[\mathclap]{a_{C_E}e^{b_{C_E}}({v_s}^*-1)}{Wavemaking resistance}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few stylistic remarks.

The period *never* denotes multiplication in math. You can use `\cdot`, but in this case no symbol is the tradition.

There's no need to enlarge the parentheses with `\Big` in this case. Even `\big` is superfluous. Remember, though, that you should use `\Bigl` before the left delimiter and `\Bigr` before the right delimiter.

Comment: loading `amsmath` doesn't harm, but with use of `mathtools` it is not needed :-) (+1 )

Comment: I liked the larger parentheses enclosing the exponentiation. I guess there’s no one right way to typeset.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I see no problem in using `\big` size, if you so prefer, but `\Big` size is too much. I'd stick with standard size, though.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions and observations

- Use `\substack{...\\...}` directives to introduce linebreaks in the text passages below the under-braces.
- Use `\vphantom` statements to align the three inner underbrace terms.
- If needed, use `\mathclap` directives (provided by the `mathtools` package) let the underbrace material protrude to the left and right.
- Use a (typographic) strut to align the "Viscous resistance" and "Wavemaking resistance" terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}} 
%% Create a typographic strut:
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\vphantom{% % use first term in summation
   \underbrace{1 - a_{\mathit{CE}}\big(}_{%
    \substack{\text{Basic viscous}\\\text{resistance}}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq23}
  C_E^* =\underbrace{%
  \underbrace{1 - a_{\mathit{CE}}\vphantom{\big(}}_{%
    \substack{\text{Basic viscous}\\ 
              \text{resistance}}}
+ \underbrace{k_{\mathit{CE}}\bigl(v_s^*-1\bigr)}_{%
    \mathclap{\substack{\text{ Linear correction}\\ 
                        \text{viscous resistance}}}}
+ \underbrace{c_{\mathit{CE}}\cdot\bigl(
    \e^{d_{\mathit{CE}}\cdot v_s^*} - \e^{d_{\mathit{CE}}}\bigr)}_{%
    \substack{\text{Non-linear correction}\\ 
              \text{viscous resistance}}}}_{%
  \text{Viscous resistance}} 
+ \underbrace{a_{\mathit{CE}}\cdot
       \e^{b_{\mathit{CE}}\cdot(v_s^*-1)}\mystrut}_{%
       \mathclap{\text{Wavemaking resistance}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! This is really helpful