# How to express a summation of product

Tags: sequence

Anyone can help me how to express "t0*t1*t2 + t0*t1*t3 +t0*t2*t3+t1*t2*t3" as a sum of product compactly in Math and latex?
The next one is
t0*t1*t2*t3 + t0*t1*t2*t4 + t0*t1*t3*t4 + t0*t2*t3*t4 + t1*t2*t3*t4,
and so on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may consider `\sum_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{0 \leq j \leq n \atop j \neq i} t_j`.

Comment: @Jinwen: ...rather use [`\substack`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12344/5764).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Werner's suggestion in his comment to the question, `\substack` looks better.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{\substack{0 \leq j \leq n \\ j \neq i}} t_j
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks to Werner & Jinwen!